# SonarLint/Java on Eclipse without SonarQube: false positives for Lombok generated classes

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok, sonarlint

I am using SonarLint on Eclipse without connecting to a SonarQube server. This setup is sufficient for me in a private Maven based Java project.

It seems, that Lombok generated code is not seen by the plugin, thus e.g. the following code raises the issue `Unused "private" fields should be removed (java:S1068)`:

```
@Data
public class Person {

   private String name;
}
```

When running against a SonarQube server, I always managed to fix this by setting `sonar.java.libraries / sonar.java.binaries` to the path, where the bytecode is generated (or the problem did not occur at all). However, running "serverless" gives me this category of errors, even if I set `sonar.java.libraries` and `sonar.java.binaries` to `target/classes` in the Eclipse `SonarLint -> Analyzer Properties` panel.

Versions:

- Eclipse: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
- SonarLint: 5.8.1.28988